# How to compute an objective function value from a matrix?

Tags: r

Suppose that we have the following beale function :

```
custom_fun <- function(x, y) {            # Create custom function in R
  z <- (1.5 - x + x*y)^2+(2.25 - x + x*y^2)^2+(2.625 - x + x*y^3)^2
  return(z)
}
```

and we have this list of positions in a matrix `m`:

```
[1] "list of respective positions"
        [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
x:  2.482116 -0.7845145 -3.370810
y: -1.031615  1.2035550  1.203555
```

How can i compute `custom_fun(x,y)` in each column with an elegant way ?
I'm wanting to store those values in the last row of the matrix `m`.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply`:

```r
custom_fun <- function(x, y) {            # Create custom function in R
  z <- (1.5 - x + x*y)^2+(2.25 - x + x*y^2)^2+(2.625 - x + x*y^3)^2
  return(z)
}

my_mat <- matrix(rnorm(10), nrow = 2, dimnames = list(c("x", "y"), NULL))

my_mat
#>        [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]        [,5]
#> x 0.5631441  0.9349816 -1.0088734 -1.364570 -1.32633896
#> y 0.4978350 -1.3265677  0.4206566 -2.532265 -0.01913554

rbind(my_mat, `fun(x, y)` = apply(my_mat, 2, function(x) custom_fun(x[1], x[2])))
#>                [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]        [,5]
#> x         0.5631441  0.9349816 -1.0088734  -1.364570 -1.32633896
#> y         0.4978350 -1.3265677  0.4206566  -2.532265 -0.01913554
#> fun(x, y) 9.3600306  9.4626106 26.4985306 749.993103 36.53218207
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>